# Python XML parse ElementTree complex XML structure

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I currently need to parse an XML document in python. However, I am struggling with the python libraries and this rather complex xml.

I have looked at the method used here: [python read complex xml with ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095586/python-read-complex-xml-with-elementtree) but it does not seem to work ?

I am using Python 2.7.7

The XML is taken from http://nvd.nist.gov/download.cfm#CURRENTXML and for instance one entry that I needs to parse looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/qdPN98VX

My relevant code looks likes this at the moment. 
I can successfully read the ID of the first entry, however, everything within the elment is not accessable. I am also not sure whether the ElementTree is the best option for a 50mb file ? :

```
from vulnsdb.models import Vuln as CVE


file = 'CVE/20140630-NVDCE-2.0-2014.xml'

tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()

for entry in root:
    c = CVE()
    c.name = entry.attrib['id']
    for details in entry:
        if details.find("{http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4}cve-id"):
            print details.find("{http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4}cve-id").text
    break
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) that parses the tree incrementally:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


TAG = '{http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0}entry'
ID = "CVE-2014-0001"

tree = ET.iterparse(open('CVE/20140630-NVDCE-2.0-2014.xml'))
for event, element in tree:
    if event == 'end' and element.tag == TAG and element.attrib.get('id') == ID:
        print ET.tostring(element)
        break
```